# Is it faster to launch an app from internal storage or from SD card?

Tags: android, performance, sd-card

I know that there are different classes of SD Cards and I also know, that there are many different kinds of internal storage (eg. my Dell Streak 5 has a 2GB Micro SD Card Class 4 built in).

However, is there a **significant** increase/decrease of speed if I have an app installed on a SD Card? Or is it the same (if you are not accounting the SD Classes)?

Comment: According to Google it makes a significant difference and they suggest only having the Media related files on the SD card.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Like Phil say, it depends of a lot of factor.

I add : Your SDCard is a really important factor, you have to check your Read / Write Speed to see if the ratios are good. They depends a lot function the brand, the reference... of your SDcard.

A lot of people say it' s really faster to run on an SDCard.

Exemple here hith the CyanogenMod http://forums.androidcentral.com/barnes-noble-nook-color/85741-cm7-faster-internal-memory-sd-card-boot.html

You have to test function your hardware.

Good luck ;).

Answer (score 0):

It depends.

No really, it does. The only way to be sure is to diagnose this yourself. IMHO I don't think there'll be a significant difference in speed if the circumstances are great. However, there probably are circumstances where the card could be significantly slower.